# Having TWO Classes in Java for 8 Solve Puzzle?

Tags: java, algorithm, sliding-tile-puzzle

I'm trying to solve the 8 Solve Puzzle using A * in Java.
I read up on it here [Solving The 8 Puzzle With A* Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251295/solving-the-8-puzzle-with-a-algorithm) .

I'm creating a data type Board with this kind of API

```
    public Board(int[][] tiles)            // create a board from an n-by-n array of tiles,
                                           // where tiles[row][col] = tile at (row, col)
    public String toString()               // string representation of this board
    public int tileAt(int row, int col)    // tile at (row, col) or 0 if blank
    public int size()                      // board size n
    public int hamming()                   // number of tiles out of place
    public int manhattan()                 // sum of Manhattan distances between tiles and goal
    public boolean isGoal()                // is this board the goal board?
    public boolean equals(Object y)        // does this board equal y?
    public Iterable<Board> neighbors()     // all neighboring boards
    public boolean isSolvable()            // is this board solvable?

    public static void main(String[] args) // unit testing (required)
}
```

(as per)
https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr18/cos226/assignments/8puzzle/index.html .

I don't understand why I need to have TWO java classes, a Board and a Solver. I understand that the Board class is going to have countless methods for hamming and Manhattan distance etc... But why? I know multiple board objects will be created each representing a different state of the 8 Solve puzzle with various different tiles present, but why do I need two classes? How exactly will a solver class solve and implement/use the Board class? Thank you.

Comment: The guide you're following has only two instances of the word "need", and neither is in relation to having two classes. So nobody said you *need* two classes; it's just a better design. A board is a different kind of thing to a solver, so they are represented by different classes.

Comment: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/assignments/8puzzle.html (this one mentions two classes) Why is having two classes a better design? Why would it be better to have (for example) an isSolvable() method for Solver as compared to the Board class?

Comment: "Why is design X better than design Y?" is quite a broad question, and you're asking about OOP, not algorithms. I would suggest reading an introductory text about software design, and if that doesn't clear it up, you will at least have a more specific question to ask.